# Fragment overlapping when using show/hide methods

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I am creating an Android App consisting a single activity i.e. `MainActivity` containing `FragmentContainerView` & `BottomNavigationView`, and 4 different fragments **Home**, **Maps**, **Controller**, and **Settings**. I want to navigate to each fragment via `BottomNavigationView` while **Home** fragment being by default visible.

I do not want fragments to recreated so I am first adding and hiding all the fragment and showing one at a time using the code below.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
...
   var activeFragment: Fragment = homeFragment

   supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
      .add(R.id.fragment_container, homeFragment, "home").hide(homeFragment)
      .add(R.id.fragment_container, mapsFragment, "maps").hide(mapsFragment)
      .add(R.id.fragment_container, controllerFragment, "controller").hide(controllerFragment)
      .add(R.id.fragment_container, settingsFragment, "settings").hide(settingsFragment)
      .show(activeFragment)
      .commit()

      val bottomNavigationView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view)
      bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener {
         when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.home -> {
               activeFragment = switchFragment(homeFragment, activeFragment)
               true
            }
            R.id.maps -> {
               activeFragment = switchFragment(mapsFragment, activeFragment)
               true
            }
            R.id.controller -> {
               activeFragment = switchFragment(controllerFragment, activeFragment)
               true
            }
            R.id.settings -> {
               activeFragment = switchFragment(settingsFragment, activeFragment)
               true
            }
            else -> false
        }
     }
...
```

**switchFragment function**

```
private fun switchFragment(fragment: Fragment, active: Fragment): Fragment {
    if (active == fragment) return fragment

    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .show(fragment).hide(active)
        .commit()

    return fragment
}
```

But the problem is that when I navigate to any other fragment **HomeFragment** don't hides instead it is overlapped by other fragment. I tried using `replace` method instead of `show/hide` but it re-creates the fragments.

[image]

If I use back button and then open the reopen app the overlapping issue resolves but when I restart the app the issue come again.

[image]

Hiding all the fragments and not showing any fragment in starting till any `BottomNavigationView` button is pressed the overlapping issue fixes but at app start there is no content on screen.

Also **I DON'T WANT ADDING BACKGROUND TO CONTAINER OR USING `REPLACE` METHOD ANSWERS, I HAVE SEEN OTHER ANSWERS AND THEY DON'T ANSWER MY QUESTION SO NOT A DUPLICATE QUESTION**